# Azure Database high DTU - High IO Avg

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to work out the cause of the high DTU on a database (its rank is S2 that is also geo replicated). On a server which is unsure if its V12 or the older (different problem).

Friday last week and this Friday we have a spike that looks like this:

[image: High DTU]

Looking at the resource stats:

`SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
ORDER BY end_time DESC`

avg CPU kicks around 3-5% during the peak
but most significantly the avg_data_io_percentage is roaming about 72% - 90%

How can I track down the IO further?

Query Performance Insight is quite useful but execution count and cpu could be misleading in this case?

TOP 5 queries per CPU consumption 
[image: Top 5 queries by cpu consumption 24 hours]

top 5 during that odd period:

[image: Top 5 queries by an hour]

Are the likely offenders the queries that that appear differently in those top five?
Is there a better way to see the IO graph or data? Am I looking at the wrong thing? :D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSMS and the built-in reports for Query Performance Insights/Query Data Store to look at IO-intensive queries. I suggest connecting to the database using SSMS and looking at the most resource intensive queries using the logical reads, logical writes, and physical reads metrics. You should find your offender in one of these.

Thanks,
Torsten

Comment: Thanks, Torsten. SQL profiler ? it has been a very long time since I've used that. It might have to wait till next Friday as that seems to be the only weird blip.

Comment: SQL profiler doesnt work ... however, there are some cunning queries here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/
I'll have to wait to dig through the IO queries ... other more pressing problems ;)